# API access to Amazon EC2 price list?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I need to implement a solution to get the Amazon instance hourly cost for each pricing model (on-demand, reserved, spot instance with predefined duration and spot instance with non-predefined duration).

Therefore, I am looking for a file from which I can get with a java code the hourly cost of an instance in each pricing strategy.

For example, I need to get the spot history price value of the spot instance from a file to use it as input for my application code. For that, I am asking how can I get the instance cost for all the different strategies proposed by Amazon to get it from a file with a code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **AWS Price List API**. It provides pricing in JSON format.

See:

- [New – AWS Price List API](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-price-list-api/)
- Documentation: [Using the AWS Price List API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/price-changes.html)

However, that API does not provide pricing of **Spot Instances** because spot instance pricing varies continually and is also different in each Availability Zone in each Region. To access Spot Pricing, use:

- Java: [`describeSpotPriceHistory`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html#describeSpotPriceHistory--)
- [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/): [`describe-spot-price-history`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-spot-price-history.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help .Is the AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI): describe-spot-price-history a paid service ? I must get the spot instance in my project and i m a beginner with AWS.

Comment: There is no charge for making the `describeSpotPriceHistory` API call, but you will need to setup an AWS account to use it.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi @ImenNeji, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: For the spot instance i succeed to have it with CLI. But i want to know how can i get it with my java code and what i need to make it.

Comment: See Java: [`describeSpotPriceHistory`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html#describeSpotPriceHistory--)

Comment: Yes i already saw it. But i want to know what i should install to create my java project. For the spot instance you told me that i must use AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI): describe-spot-price-history that i succeed to make it but for the Java: describeSpotPriceHistory i didn't find yet a solution to impléments. Please consider that i m a beginner with AWS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AWS Price List API for Java](https://github.com/wnameless/aws-price-list-api). BTW, I am the author of this library.